# Can not post HTML request data to controller

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms

I am having an issue where in a website i am working on a form will not run the code when the button is pressed, this litterally worked and i have no idea what changed that broke it.

```
<form action="{{action('Admin\AdminResponsibleController@assign')}}"  method="post" id="assignParty">
    @csrf
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button> 

        </div>
    @endif
    @if ($message = Session::get('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-block">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button> 
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </div>
    @endif
    <input type="radio" name="party_type" value="responsible" checked>Responsible Party<br>  
    <input type="radio" name="party_type" value="responsibleTwo"> Second Responsible Party<br> 
    <input type="radio" name="party_type" value="witness"> Witness <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remove" value="remove"> Remove Selected Assignment <br>
    <input type="hidden" id="userId" name="userId" value="<?php echo $user->id; ?>">
</form>
<button type="submit" form="assignParty" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

route

```
    Route::post('admin/viewPatient/assign', 'Admin\AdminResponsibleController@assign');
```

code that i am trying to run, the dd is for testing, it never even gets there

```
 public function assign(Request $request)
{     
    dd('hit');
    if($request->input('userId') != null){
        $patient = intval($request->input('userId'));
        $patient = User::where('id', $patient)->first();
    }  /**/

    $party = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))
                // We want to be sure that Admins and Patients can't be responsible parts, if they need to be we can create another account for them
                // Having patients be able to be repsonsible parties would confuse the patient and could lead to buggy code
                ->first();

    if($party != null){
        if($party->user_type == 'Admin' || $party->user_type == 'Patient'){
            return redirect()->back()->with(['message', 'Can not assign this user']);
        }
    }
    // setup remove user variable as false
    $removeUser = false;
    // if the email is null, remove user is true
    if($request->input('remove') != null){
        $removeUser = true;
    } else if($request->input('email') == null){
        return redirect()->back()->with(['message', 'Please include an email']);
    }
    // switch case to switch to different statements based on the input of party_type
    switch ($request->input('party_type')) {
        case 'responsible':
            $this->check($request, $party, 'responsible_party', 'Responsible Party', $removeUser, $patient);
            break;
        case 'responsibleTwo':
            $this->check($request, $party, 'responsible_party_two', 'Second Responsible Party', $removeUser, $patient);
            break;
        case 'financial':
            $this->check($request, $party, 'financial', 'Financially Responsible Party', $removeUser, $patient);
            break;
        case 'legal':
            $this->check($request, $party, 'legal', 'Legal Rep', $removeUser, $patient);
            break;
        case 'witness':
            $this->check($request, $party, 'witness', 'Witness', $removeUser, $patient);
            break;
        default:
            // in future versions please include a link to dispatch a support request
            // this really shouldn't happen, but a default case should be included in case something somehow goes wrong
            throw new \Exception('You must provide a party type.');
            break;

    }
    // return to the view with a message that the party has been assigned
    return redirect()->back()->with(['success', 'Party Updated sucessfully']);
}
```

I just updated this post with changes i made to the code

Comment: Can you explain what's happening that is "not working"? Does the page not reload, do you get an error...? Are you using JavaScript on the form submission? Is it interfering at all (anything in your JS console)?

Comment: i click the submit button and nothing happens, no reload, no error, nothing

Comment: use only one type=button inside your form, if you need to create another button use <a>.

for submit button place it inside your form, if you want to place it from outside your form, you can use it from javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved, there was an unclosed form tag elsewhere in the page

```
<form action="{{action('Patient\UploadController@adminUpload')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
                        <input id="user" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="user" value="{{$user->id}}" required autofocus>
                        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
                    <span class="text-danger">{{$errors->first('file')}}</span>`enter code here`
```

changed to

```
<form action="{{action('Patient\UploadController@adminUpload')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
                        <input id="user" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="user" value="{{$user->id}}" required autofocus>
                        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
                    </form>
                    <span class="text-danger">{{$errors->first('file')}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the action to route?:

```
 Route::post('admin/viewPatient/assign', 'Admin\AdminResponsibleController@assign')->name('assign.post');

<form action="{{route('assign.post')}}"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="assignParty">
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-route

- Also you should have the inputs closed like: `/>`
- you could try to run `php artisan cache:clear` in your terminal.
- you could try to run `php artisan route:cache` in your terminal.

## Wait, your button is outside of your form!!

```
<form>
   inputs

   <button type="submit" form="assignParty" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: try. artisan route:clear, is the path in the route pointing to the right controller file/folder?

Comment: is the rendered html showing the action="" properly?

Comment: yes, right path, right file name, right function name. this used to work, idk what changed, i made changes to simplify it and it still will not post to the controller

Comment: How would i check if it is showing the action properly? how should i close them? i have other code that uses the same setup that works fine

Comment: your button is outside of your form!!

Comment: button inside the form changes nothing

Comment: please, load the page and right click, then "view page source". Please upload an image of what you see there in the form part

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an input tag instead of a button tag.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```